# PHP SQL-Server connection error

Tags: php, sql-server, connection

I am trying to connect to sql server using php using following code:

```
$myServer = "server";
$myUser = "username";
$myPass = "password";
$myDB = "test";

//connection to the database
$dbhandle = mssql_connect($myServer, $myUser, $myPass)
  or die("Couldn't connect to SQL Server on $myServer");
```

**Getting following error:**

> Fatal error: Call to undefined
>   function mssql_connect() in
>   /var/www/echdp/mssql_connection.php on
>   line 26

**Using php version**

> PHP Version 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.2

I have googled it many time and also try to search php_mssql extension but not found. Also search to install mssql extension but not find a useful link/tutorial .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If mssql_connect() is not available then it sounds like the MSSQL module isn't installed.  You can check this with the phpinfo() function which will list all your compiled modules.

On Ubuntu you should be able to install the module from a package:-

> apt-get install php5-sybase

(this is the Sybase/MSSQL Server module for php5)

...or as the previous answers states, compile from source with MSSQL flag

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried recompiling PHP with the switch --with-mssql[=DIR]?

Comment: can you add some more detail that how to use switch.